# Why are some processes assigned parent PIDs even though they don't have a parent?

Tags: windows-server-2008, process

There are a number of processes that are started with a fake (non-existent PID). An example of this is a csrss.exe process. It starts up, and the parent process PID assigned doesn't exist. If you look in procexp.exe, "Parent" is listed as "(524)" (524 is the random, non-existent parent PID in this case). Why are these assigned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Client/Server Runtime Subsystem (CSRSS or `csrss.exe`) is spawned by the Session Manager Subsystem (SMSS or `smss.exe`). SMSS is spawned by System (which always has a PID of 4) under Session 0 for OS services. Additionally, SMSS is spawned in Session 1 (the user session) with the sole job of starting CSRSS and WinLogon.  Once those two are started, the Session 1 SMSS terminates.

Hence, the phantom parent ID you are seeing is the PID of the Session 1 SMSS process that has already terminated.

Comment: Thanks! Since the PID is getting reassigned to other processes, it looks like processes started by smss are the children of another process. I can just compare timestamps to see if the children are newer then the parent; if so, I can just ignore them.